# How can i fix an if statement within an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I'm teaching myself java and I'm a few weeks in, decided to make a program with several options in it.
First part is to select between two animals, in this case a seal and hippo.
After that the part I'm having trouble with after selecting the seal is that I want options after selecting the seal, such as repeating the action, terminating it, or asking for proper input when user types something random.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class animal {

    //Animal variables
    String name;
    String type;

    //Method or subroutine, something an object belonging to the class can do
    void sound() {
    System.out.println(name + " was petted! " + name + " went 'Gauuu!'");
    }

}



public class Objectmethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Creating an object under the class of Animal
        animal animal1 = new animal();
        animal1.name = "Baby Elephant Seal";
        animal1.type = "Seal";


        //Creating second animal
        animal animal2 = new animal();
        animal2.name = "Hippopotawhateveritis";
        animal2.type = "Hippopotamus or however you spell it";


        //Beginning prompt for user input
        System.out.println("Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?");

        //The code to recieve input of the user
        String select = scanner1.nextLine();

        //check user input to select correct object
        while(true)
            if(select.equals("seal")){

                //Command that the animal sounds has.
                animal1.sound();

                //Prompt if the user would like to repeat
                System.out.println("Would you like to pet the seal again?");

                //second input recieving from user
                String input = scanner2.nextLine();

                    //Checks user input for yes no or random crap
                    if(input.equals("yes")){
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(input.equals("no")){
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Answer yes or no you derpface.");
                        input = scanner2.nextLine();

                    }
            }
            else if(select.equals("hippo")){
                animal2.sound();
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You cray cray. Just pick one.");
                select = scanner1.nextLine();
            }
        System.out.println("Thank you for participating.");
    }

}
```

Typing seal works fine
then when input gibberish to get the else response of "Answer yes or no you derpface"
it works the first time, then the second time it goes back up to the response.
This is what happens

```
Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?
seal
Baby Elephant Seal was petted! Baby Elephant Seal went 'Gauuu!'
Would you like to pet the seal again?
"randominput"
Answer yes or no you derpface.
"secondrandominput"
Baby Elephant Seal was petted! Baby Elephant Seal went 'Gauuu!'
Would you like to pet the seal again?
no
Thank you for participating.
```

What do I have wrong that causes it to go to the "if" instead of the "else"? -Solved-

**New problem.** Here is what the last part of the script looks like after my attempt at fixing it.
I believe the issue is occurring at the chunk of code before termination, however I'm not sure what exactly it is as I've tried to apply the aforementioned fix and it didn't work. (The else statement just above the "Thank you for participating" code)  **Solved**

(The issue was that having moved the first "while(true)" above everything else. I moved it back to where it was originally below "scanner1" and it is now functioning properly

**-Note-** This is after applying the first "while(true)" to robustly repeat petting of animals.

```
else{
    while(!select.equals("seal") && !select.equals("hippo")){
    System.out.println("You cray cray. Just pick one.");
    select = scanner1.nextLine();
    }
```

**Example of the issue:** (Quotes represent user input.)

```
Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?
"neither"
You cray cray. Just pick one.
"neither"
You cray cray. Just pick one.
"seal"
Thank you for participating.
Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?
```

**The way I want it to occur:** (Quotes represent user input.)

```
Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?
"neither"
You cray cray. Just pick one.
"neither"
You cray cray. Just pick one.
"seal"
Baby Elephant Seal was petted! Baby Elephant Seal went 'Gauuu!'
Would you like to pet the seal again?
...
...
//Rest of the program (Confirming repeated petting, or termination of program)
```

Comment: If i keep typing in gibberish or unrecognized input, it alternates between the correct response and going to the "yes" response.

Comment: One suggestion I would make right off the bat is get rid of one of the scanners. There is no meaningful use for having two scanners here. Also, you use select to get the initial string but are using a different string to get new input inside the while loop, but still do comparisons based on the original string.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether I needed two or not. When would be the proper time to use more than one scanner? (Packages,Classes,Objects..?)

Comment: One reason you might need more than 1 scanner is if you are scanning from multiple sources (i.e.- scanning from system.in with one scanner and scanning from a file with another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix one of your problems. Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

```
else{
    while (!input.equals("yes") && !input.equals("no")){
        System.out.println("Answer yes or no you derpface.");
        input = scanner2.nextLine();
    }
}
```

You have another issue though. You poll for the user response before the `while(true)` loop.

NOTE: After reviewing your code further, it seems like this functionality was intended. If you want to make your code more robust to continually pet all animals, see the code below.

You should edit your code to be like this:

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?");

    //The code to recieve input of the user
    String select = scanner1.nextLine();
    .
    .
    .
    // the rest of your code
```

Per OP's request, here should be the fully edited code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class animal {

    // Animal variables
    String name;
    String type;

    // Method or subroutine, something an object belonging to the class can do
    void sound() {
        System.out.println(name + " was petted! " + name + " went 'Gauuu!'");
    }

}

public class Objectmethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Creating an object under the class of Animal
        animal animal1 = new animal();
        animal1.name = "Baby Elephant Seal";
        animal1.type = "Seal";

        // Creating second animal
        animal animal2 = new animal();
        animal2.name = "Hippopotawhateveritis";
        animal2.type = "Hippopotamus or however you spell it";

        // check user input to select correct object
        while (true) {

            // Beginning prompt for user input
            System.out.println("Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?");

            // The code to recieve input of the user
            String select = scanner1.nextLine();

            if (select.equals("seal")) {

                // Command that the animal sounds has.
                animal1.sound();

                // Prompt if the user would like to repeat
                System.out.println("Would you like another animal?");

                // second input recieving from user
                String input = scanner2.nextLine();

                // Checks user input for yes no or random crap
                if (input.equals("yes")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (input.equals("no")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    while (!input.equals("yes") && !input.equals("no")) {
                        System.out.println("Answer yes or no you derpface.");
                        input = scanner2.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            } else if (select.equals("hippo")) {
                animal2.sound();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You cray cray. Just pick one.");
                select = scanner1.nextLine();
            }  
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for participating.");
    }
}
```

Comment: One of his major problems is using two separate strings but mixing comparisons. When he pets the Seal, then says yes, it's going to mess up future runs because he's still doing comparisons based on the string that is only obtained before the loop.

Comment: Yea, this is true too. I'll edit my answer to fix this issue as well.

Comment: Applied what you've put up there and it works like a charm. Thank you. However I've encountered another problem. Now the end statement is failing to run. The gibberish response is fine, however after selecting seal, it just skips the inner If statement and goes straight to the end. I've tried to apply the "while(...)" like you showed however it still terminated to the last part and then proceeded to restart the entire program.

Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?- 
asdf- 
You cray cray. Just pick one.-
seal-
Thank you for participating.-
Would you like to pet the seal, or the hippo?

Comment: I've edited my Answer. This should fix your issue. If it doesn't please let me know.

Comment: @DavidJones The code that you've stated is exactly how I have my code set up and the -else- reply of the inner IF statement is working fine. However the Else reply of the Seal or Hippo select isn't functioning properly and has the same problem as previous IF statement. So it says "You cray cray. Just pick one". Then if given the "seal" answer, it skips the smaller IF statement within the "seal" object. I've tried applying your fix with "seal" and "hippo" however it doesn't seem to be the same problem and isn't fixed. I'll edit my main post to show what I mean.

Comment: Pardon me, it isn't the same issue as the first. The else functions fine, but when given a proper answer such as "seal" it ignores all of the code within the "seal" chunk and just goes to termination.